# How to delete subdocument but keep contents in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I ran a script that populated my collection with approximately 60k documents.  Because of a mistype, it created subdocuments within all of the documents and contains duplicate information. I really don't need/want the subdocument, but I don't want to delete the it entirely, because I want a field within it to remain.

This is my document structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "title" : "",
    "url" : "",
    "description" : "", 
    "author" : "",
    "publishedAt" : "",
    "content" : "" 
    "source" : {
        "id" : "Source",
        "name" : "Source"
    },
    "urlToImage" : ""
}
```

Ultimately what I want to do, if possible, is remove the source subdocument, but keep the name field.  Below is what I want.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "title" : "",
    "url" : "",
    "description" : "", 
    "author" : "",
    "publishedAt" : "",
    "content" : "" 
    "name" : "Source"
    "urlToImage" : ""
}
```

I know this would be a multi-part query.  I just don't want to make a mistake and delete the entire subdocument without pulling out the fields first.

Answer (score 0):

### option 1 - $rename and $unset

1. use [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator to rename `source.name` to `name`

   - perhaps with some check (filter) that you are not going to overwrite existing `name` with `null`
2. then remove the `source` subdocument using [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator

   - again, just to be sure, you can add filter to make sure that the `name` field already exists in document where you are unsetting the `source`

### option 2 - find and $set+$unset

1. retrieve the document
2. update the document using $set and $unset

Example (in Python):

```py
while True:
    doc = db.find_one({
         '_id': 'foobar',
         'source.name': {'$exists': True},
    })
    res = db.update_one(
        {
            '_id': 'foobar',
            'source.name': doc['source']['name'],
        }, {
            '$set': {'name': doc['source']['name']},
            '$unset': {'source': ''},
        }
    )
    if res.modified_count == 1:
        break
    # if nothing was modified then somebody has updated
    # the source.name right after our find_one()
```

Comment: In option 1, $rename seems to only apply to fields.  The documentation doesn't mention to the data within the field thats being renamed.  I'm a little apprehensive to try this one.  In option to, is this applying to all the documents, or just one to see if it works?